# Spark: Sorting RDD from multiple files without using collect

Tags: sorting, apache-spark, collect

I've "uploaded" N files from a certain directory in a single RDD

```
val data = sc.textFile("file:///myPath/*.txt")
```

For example my 2 files contain 5 lines each.

File 1

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

File 2

```
F
G
H
I
J
```

If I add a sortBy to my code:

```
val sortedData = data.sortBy(x => x)
```

I do not get my sorted data, but just a random RDD:

```
J
B
C
E
A
D
G
F
H
I
```

Collect could help me, but

1)it's not ideal for large RDD

2)instead of a RDD, it returns an array (which I should re-parallelize)

Thanks in advance

FF

Comment: That should work like that. How are you verifying the results of the sort?

Comment: "Printing" my result... sortedData.foreach(println)

Comment: sortedData.foreach(println) will not print anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the union method if you have multiple rdds:

```
val rdd = rdd1.union(rdd2)
```

This will aggregate both rdds and then you can sort on that new rdd.

But in your case, you can read all the data into the same rdd and then sort on it.

EDIT:

I've created 2 files containing file1 and file2 and I've done the following:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Eliasah.
And what if I had N files?
Could I use a single command to "union them all at once"?

Comment: I've also found this code "sc.textFile(','.join(files)) ", but I can't get its syntax

Comment: If you have N files. You can use a wildcard per example in the sc.textFile method to read them all into one RDD

Comment: I'm already loading N files all at once with <<< val data = sc.textFile("file:///myPath/*.txt") >>> ... The problem is that the sorting on that RDD isn't working if I load them in this way... I would like to know if there's a more efficient way to load them without having to use collect in order to sort them properly

Comment: You are not able to sort the RDD? is it a RDD[String]? What is the size of the data? what do you mean by it's not working?

Comment: Yes it's a RDD[String]... Just the one of my question(One letter per String)... I'd like to "print" the output sorted alphabetically (A,B,C,ecc...) and not random... I'm using <<< val sortedData = data.sortBy(x => x) >>> but as you can see in the question, if I print the RDD (<<< sortedData.foreach(println) >>>) the output is someting like J,B,C,ecc...

Comment: it works fine with me! how are you seeing the output data? what command?

Comment: Eliasah, maybe this pic can help to understand what I am getting as result... http://it.tinypic.com/r/332mcya/8

Comment: absolutely, I did, thank you... you're using take(10) knowing that the RDD has 10 elements... but what if you don't know exactly how many elements are contained in the RDD? I could ignore the exact number of elements, and still want to sort the RDD... but MORE IMPORTANT, Take returns an Array, not a RDD (just as collect)

Comment: I believe that it is a concurrency pb with the input output but if you save the rdd it will be actually sorted.

Comment: It seems that saving the RDD as a TextFile is problem-free.
Anyway, I've never had problem with sorting with a single textfile loaded in a RDD printed with rdd.foreach.println... Today I've learned that I must pay attention when loading N files and then using rdd.foreach.println... thanks a lot aliasah!

Comment: @Panto if it was helpful to you consider voting and accepting the answer.

Comment: Answer accepted... but can't vote yet... reputation still too low for the moment ;-)
Can't get more reputation point XD

Comment: @maasg: you're right... just accepted answer ;-)... since I'm quite new to stackoverflow, I'm still confused about voting system... can the answer be voted too?

Comment: need rep 15 :) ... I need vote for my questions since I'm just asking and not answering :P